# How to reset the global variable prev?

Tags: c, tree

This is the C solution for Leetcode 114. Flatten Binary Tree to Linked List

```
struct TreeNode* prev = NULL;

void flatten(struct TreeNode* root){
    if (root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    flatten(root->right);
    flatten(root->left);
    root->right = prev;
    root->left = NULL;
    prev = root;
}
```

When tested with

```
[1,2,5,3,4,null,6]
[0]
```

It would have this error output

```
[1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,5,null,6]
[0,null,1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,5,null,6]
```

The correct output should be

```
[1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,5,null,6]
[0]
```

But if tested individually, both cases can pass, this  is because the prev is a global variable.So how to reset this value?

Comment: Seems "how to reset the global variable" is the wrong question/approach. The obvious solution to the actual problem: work out a way to implement without a global variable.

Comment: yeah, there are many other solutions. But this solution is inspired from a java version, quite concise. I want to see if it can work.

Comment: Either the java version works in all cases or it is just as broken as your version in which case it is not a good base to work off. Using a global variable is totally the wrong thing to do and a bad place to start. I very much doubt the original version or your version can work with the use of a global variable.

Comment: In Java, the prev is a private variable in class Solution so that it doesn't have this problem. I thinked over and agree with your comment that global variable in C should be avoided. Thanks.

Comment: A better solution (IMO) would be to return the "flattened" sub-tree from the function, and use it to add to the list.

Comment: make sense, I will try this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an iterative solution, if you'd be interested:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct TreeNode *left;
 *     struct TreeNode *right;
 * };
 */


void flatten(struct TreeNode* root) {
    struct TreeNode* lr;

    while (root != NULL) {
        if (root->left != NULL) {
            lr = root->left;

            while (lr->right != NULL) {
                lr = lr->right;
            }

            lr->right = root->right;
            root->right = root->left;
            root->left = NULL;
        }

        root = root->right;
    }
}
```

And here is LeetCode's recursive solution in Java with comments:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    
    private TreeNode flattenTree(TreeNode node) {
        
        // Handle the null scenario
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }
            
        // For a leaf node, we simply return the
        // node as is.
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            return node;
        }
        
        //Recursively flatten the left subtree
        TreeNode leftTail = this.flattenTree(node.left);
        
        // Recursively flatten the right subtree
        TreeNode rightTail = this.flattenTree(node.right);
        
        // If there was a left subtree, we shuffle the connections
        // around so that there is nothing on the left side
        // anymore.
        if (leftTail != null) {
            leftTail.right = node.right;
            node.right = node.left;
            node.left = null;
        }
        
        // We need to return the "rightmost" node after we are
        // done wiring the new connections. 
        return rightTail == null ? leftTail : rightTail;
    }
    
    public void flatten(TreeNode root) {
        
        this.flattenTree(root);
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.